# No sound devices on Kubuntu 20.04 with last three Linux kernels (5.8.0-41/38/36-generic)

Tags: nvidia, sound, kubuntu

On one of my machines (*HP zBook 17 G2*) **Kubuntu 20.04** (with all latest updates installed) on Linux kernels `Linux 5.8.0-41-generic`, `Linux 5.8.0-38-generic` and `Linux 5.8.0-38-generic` I have no sound devices detected after boot and login. When I boot with kernel `Linux 5.4.0-65-generic` everything works as expected.

### More Info

*Please note that all info below is from the same machine*

#### Linux 5.8.0-41-generic - No Sound

```
# uname -srvpio
Linux 5.8.0-41-generic #46~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:52:23 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

#### Linux 5.8.0-38-generic - No Sound

```
# uname -srvpio
Linux 5.8.0-38-generic #43~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 12 16:39:47 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

#### Linux 5.8.0-36-generic - No Sound

```
# name -srvpio
Linux 5.8.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 10:15:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

#### Linux 5.4.0-65-generic - Sound Works

```
# uname -srvpio
Linux 5.4.0-65-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 17:25:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3228 Analog [ALC3228 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

### Questions

- How to fix it?
- Or where I could find more information (logs, crash dumps) for bug report?
- What to look for at logs `boot.log`, `kern.log` and `syslog`?

### Edit:

- Linux 5.8.0-44-generic - No sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by upgrading to **Kubuntu 22.04**, kernel `Linux 5.19.0-35-generic`